# Covariance of a standard normal variable

Tags: normal-distribution, independence, covariance

Let  be a standard normal random variable. Another random variable is determined as follows. We flip a fair coin (independent from ). In case of Heads, we let =. In case of Tails, we let =−.

Compute $cov(X,Y)$. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Getting either Heads or Tails is equally likely, hence a probability of $1/2$.

If Heads with p=1/2 (fair coin):

$Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = E[XY] = E[X^2] = var(X) -(E[X])^2 = var(X) = 1$

If Tails with p=1/2:

$Cov(X,Y) = E[-X^2] = - E[X^2] = -var(X) = - 1$

$Cov(X,Y)= 1/2*1 + 1/2*-1 = 0$.

X and Y are independent if P(Y │X) = P (Y). If we know x, we know y is either ±x, so X gives us some useful information about Y. Therefore X and Y are not independent?

On the other hand, I get different with a contrasting approach. Since X is standard normal r.v. which means that it is symmetric around 0, then it has the following PDF:

$$fx(x) = 1/sqrt(2π) * e^{-x^2/2}$$

Now, if the coin toss happens to be heads (with probability 1/2) then the PDF of Y is exactly the same as above. What happens however if the result is tails?

Given that X is symmetric then Y=-X is exactly the same as Y=X, which can be shown as follows:

$$f_Y(-x) = 1/sqrt(2π) * e^{-(-x)^2/2} = 1/sqrt(2π) * e^{-x^2/2} = f_Y(x) = f_X(x)$$

The above then implies that Y=X no matter the results of the coin toss, so Y is normal and the cov(X,Y) = cov(X,X) = var(X) = 1, as X is standard normal. Finally, since X and Y are identical, then both X and Y are dependent.

The definite question is $cov(X,Y)$ equal to 1 or 0 ?

Comment: The marginal density of $Y$ is indeed the standard normal density, but that does not imply $X=Y$. By the same flawed reasoning, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normal, you could also say $X=Y$, which is not true either.

Comment: Thanks for your pointing that out @angryavian . To understand your first point, does the marginal density of $Y$ signify $Y$ is normal? Or what do you mean? So I assume that the $-X$ does play an important role, thus the $(,)=0$?

Comment: Yes, it does imply that $Y$ is normal, but that statement says nothing about the nature of its dependence with $X$.

Comment: @angryavian You said that $Y$ being normal does not imply $=$. Okay, this makes sense. What I do know is that each coin flip $Y$ is independent of $X$, as stated in the context. What I also know is that if X and Y are independent then $Cov(X,Y)=0$, however, not the other way around. A zero covariance does not imply that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. The magnitude of covariance depends on the variables since it is not a normalized measure. As a result, the values themselves are not a clear indication of how strong the linear relationship is. Do I also have to correlate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your related question ([Probability of a standard normal random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4425695/probability-of-a-standard-normal-random-variables/4425705?noredirect=1#comment9261713_4425705)), you simply need to make your conditioning on the external source of randomness (say, $C$, being the independent, random coin flip) much more explicit. Then you will find that your first set of calculations is correct. Note that without this conditioning, $Y$ does not take on any fixed formula yet. To illustrate, we start with
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y) &= \mathbb{E}{XY} - \mathbb{E}{X} \mathbb{E}{Y} .
\end{align}
$$
This is always true for any two random variables $X$, $Y$. However, we want to condition on $C$ and use the law of total expectation so that we have a concrete formula for what $Y$ is. For example, for the first term,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}XY &= \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[XY \mid C = \text{"Heads"}] + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[XY \mid C = \text{"Tails"}] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[X^2] + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[-X^2] = 0.
\end{align}
$$
The remaining computations proceed identically. Now your intuition and reasoning that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent (even though they are uncorrelated) is perfectly correct.

As for the density of $Y$, the correct computation follows again from performing the conditioning correctly:
$$
\begin{align}
f_Y(x) = \frac{1}{2} f_{Y \mid C = \text{"Heads"}}(x) + \frac{1}{2} f_{Y \mid C = \text{"Tails"}}(x) = \frac{1}{2} f_X(x) + \frac{1}{2} f_{-X}(x) &=f_X(x).
\end{align}
$$
(In the end we simply use the symmetry of the standard normal random variable $X$.) Note that $f_Y(x) = f_X(x)$ does *not* mean that $X = Y$; it simply means they have the same density but as our previous computations reveal, they are intricately linked by the external coin toss.

Comment: God bless you @JKL . You just saved me many hours of overthinking. One last thing though, instead of me intuiting and reasoning that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, could it be that the context and the computed covariance is "not enough information to determine" the independence of $X$ and $Y$? Thanks again for your amazing answer!

Comment: In general, uncorrelated (which is essentially covariance up to scaling) does not mean independent (which is one of the first things you learn in any statistics/probability course) -- what is always true is the converse (independence $\Rightarrow$ uncorrelated). So independence is something that needs to be determined by context (or set as an assumption).