# Probability of a standard normal random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, independence

I am posting a separate question (in order to follow the community's guidelines) based on my previous post with the same context as before:

Let  be a standard normal random variable. Another random variable is determined as follows. We flip a fair coin (independent from ). In case of Heads, we let =. In case of Tails, we let =−.

Find (+≤0).

If Heads with p=1/2 (Y=X):

$$ P(X+Y<=0) = P(X+X<=0) = P(2X<=0) = P(X<=0) =1/2$$ (because standard normal r.v.)

If Tails with p=1/2 (Y=-X):

$$P(X+Y<=0) = P(X-X<=0) = P(0<=0) = 1$$

Therefore, $P(X+Y<=0) = 1/2*1/2 + 1/2*1 = 3/4$

On the other hand, $P(X+Y<=0)$ is $P(2X<=0)$, which is the same as $P(X<=0)$, since X and Y are identical then the probability always equals 0.5 regardless of the output?

Is $P(X+Y<=0)$ equal to 3/4 or 1/2?

Comment: You are making the same error as in your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4425686/covariance-of-a-standard-normal-variable). $X$ and $Y$ having the same distribution does not imply that $X=Y$.

Comment: So definitely $(+<=0)=3/4$ or am I missing something? @angryavian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can simply offer a rewriting of your first solution (which is the correct one) with some clearer notation that makes the dependence on the external source of randomness explicit -- perhaps this should then make it clear why it is the correct one. Let $C$ be the outcome of the independent coin toss. Then $Y$ is a function of $C$ and $X$:
$$
Y = \begin{cases}
X & \text{if } C = \text{"Heads"}, \\
-X & \text{if } C = \text{"Tails"}. \\
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, by the law of total probability,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X + Y \leq 0) &= \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{P}(X + Y \leq 0 \mid C = \text{"Heads"}) + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{P}(X + Y \leq 0 \mid C = \text{"Tails"}) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{P}(X + X \leq 0) + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{P}(X - X \leq 0) \\
&= \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{4} .
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JKL . I was on the wrong track by assuming that $X=Y$. Your answer makes it much more visually clearer. Since this question is based on a previous one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4425686/covariance-of-a-standard-normal-variable?noredirect=1#comment9261681_4425686), perhaps you could shed some light or provide a useful hint as to how to tell whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent or not. Cheers!